# With Jackson is it possible to just ignore all cyclic relationship without having to add annotation?

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-lib

Jackson 2.0 has pretty good support for cyclic reference, however, it seems that all require to annotate the POJO classes. What if I cannot edit the java classes I want to serialize to json, but want to just ignore cyclic reference like the json lib jsonConfig.setCycleDetectionStrategy(CycleDetectionStrategy.LENIENT) which basically ignore cyclic reference when one occurs.

Answer (score 2):

No. Jackson does not do full cycle detection; identity checks are only done when annotation indicates that they are needed.